# Blur the bg image in a container but not the content inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a column with a background image set to `cover` and inside the column there's another div that holds the content: title, description and tags.

The content is set to `display: none;` and the background image is in focus.

When I hover over the background image, it blurs and the content appears.

However, the content is also getting blurred and I can't figure out how to remove the blur and bring the content into focus while keeping the background image blurred.

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/499hes8f/3/

The content might be a bit hard to see but it's there, just move your mouse to the top left.

```css
.btn-dark {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

a.btn-dark:after {
  display: none!important;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.project {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project-bg {
  height: 500px;
}

.blur:hover:not(.project-content2) {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.09);
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.project-content2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 75px;
}

.project .project-content,
.project .project-content2 {
  display: none;
}

.project-first .project-content,
.project-first .project-content2 {
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 99999999999999999999999999999;
}

.project:hover .project-content,
.project:hover .project-content2 {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  -o-animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 99999999999999999999999999999999;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding project">
  <div class="project-bg blur" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0JQxkW7.jpg') center center / cover;">
    <div class="project-content2">
      <h2><a href="#">Through The Telescope</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed mauris nunc. Sed vel aliquet felis. Sed eget laoreet sem. Cras in sagittis felis. Aliquam sollicitudin porta est vitae volutpat. Mauris et cursus massa. Nullam ante felis, gravida
        eu leo sit amet, sodales accumsan justo. Sed sit amet leo tristique, dictum mauris vitae, aliquam nibh. Curabitur a dui lectus. Ut molestie, ipsum vel lacinia auctor, odio magna pellentesque risus, vestibulum facilisis justo mi quis mi. Vivamus
        semper ipsum eget tincidunt ullamcorper.</p>
      <div class="tags-button hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Tag</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to solve this is to put your content and background image in two separate DIVs.

I left the content in `.project-content2` and moved the BG into its own DIV with `.project-bg .blur`. Both of those are wrapped in a `.project-wrapper` DIV.

Then position the project background DIV absolutely inside the project wrapper DIV:

```
.project-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
}

.project-bg {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
 }
```

And refactor the hover selector to `.project:hover .blur`.

```css
.btn-dark {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

a.btn-dark:after {
  display: none!important;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.project {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project-wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
}

.project-bg {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
 }

.project:hover .blur {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.09);
}

.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.project-content2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 75px;
}

.project .project-content,
.project .project-content2 {
  display: none;
}

.project-first .project-content,
.project-first .project-content2 {
  display: block;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 99999999999999999999999999999;
}

.project:hover .project-content,
.project:hover .project-content2 {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  -o-animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  animation: fadeInFromNone 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: 99999999999999999999999999999999;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInFromNone {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding project">
  <div class="project-wrapper">
  
    <div class="project-bg blur" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0JQxkW7.jpg') center center / cover;"></div>
    
    <div class="project-content2">
      <h2><a href="#">Through The Telescope</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed mauris nunc. Sed vel aliquet felis. Sed eget laoreet sem. Cras in sagittis felis. Aliquam sollicitudin porta est vitae volutpat. Mauris et cursus massa. Nullam ante felis, gravida
        eu leo sit amet, sodales accumsan justo. Sed sit amet leo tristique, dictum mauris vitae, aliquam nibh. Curabitur a dui lectus. Ut molestie, ipsum vel lacinia auctor, odio magna pellentesque risus, vestibulum facilisis justo mi quis mi. Vivamus
        semper ipsum eget tincidunt ullamcorper.</p>
      <div class="tags-button hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Tag</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding project">
  <div class="project-bg blur" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0JQxkW7.jpg') center center / cover;">
    <div class="project-content2">
      <h2><a href="#">Through The Telescope</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed mauris nunc. Sed vel aliquet felis. Sed eget laoreet sem. Cras in sagittis felis. Aliquam sollicitudin porta est vitae volutpat. Mauris et cursus massa. Nullam ante felis, gravida eu leo sit amet, sodales accumsan justo. Sed sit amet leo tristique, dictum mauris vitae, aliquam nibh. Curabitur a dui lectus. Ut molestie, ipsum vel lacinia auctor, odio magna pellentesque risus, vestibulum facilisis justo mi quis mi. Vivamus semper ipsum eget tincidunt ullamcorper.</p>
      <div class="tags-button hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Tag</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make this easier for yourself.

Make   `<div class="project-bg blur" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0JQxkW7.jpg') center center / cover;">` it's own container and place the

```
<div class="project-content2">
      <h2><a href="#">Through The Telescope</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed mauris nunc. Sed vel aliquet felis. Sed eget laoreet sem. Cras in sagittis felis. Aliquam sollicitudin porta est vitae volutpat. Mauris et cursus massa. Nullam ante felis, gravida eu leo sit amet, sodales accumsan justo. Sed sit amet leo tristique, dictum mauris vitae, aliquam nibh. Curabitur a dui lectus. Ut molestie, ipsum vel lacinia auctor, odio magna pellentesque risus, vestibulum facilisis justo mi quis mi. Vivamus semper ipsum eget tincidunt ullamcorper.</p>
      <div class="tags-button hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Tag</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

on it's own level.

So like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding project">
  <div class="project-bg blur" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0JQxkW7.jpg') center center / cover;">
  </div>
<div class="project-content2">
      <h2><a href="#">Through The Telescope</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sed mauris nunc. Sed vel aliquet felis. Sed eget laoreet sem. Cras in sagittis felis. Aliquam sollicitudin porta est vitae volutpat. Mauris et cursus massa. Nullam ante felis, gravida eu leo sit amet, sodales accumsan justo. Sed sit amet leo tristique, dictum mauris vitae, aliquam nibh. Curabitur a dui lectus. Ut molestie, ipsum vel lacinia auctor, odio magna pellentesque risus, vestibulum facilisis justo mi quis mi. Vivamus semper ipsum eget tincidunt ullamcorper.</p>
      <div class="tags-button hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Tag</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

.project {
position: relative;
}

.project-bg {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
backgrounds-size: cover;
}
```

Play about with the content styles and the z-index. I haven't tested the code either, but I think it'll put you on the right track.

You should be able to target the background container more accurately this way without affecting the content as well.

Let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dylan nailed it. When it comes to properties like blur or opacity filters, you'll need to separate content from background.

I'd like to offer a re-factored version that simplifies things for you significantly. This isn't can't be directly implemented into what you provided but it's a simpler, scalable version.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnjq88nd/8/

HTML:

```
<div class="project">
  <div class="project-1">
    <div class="project-content">
      My Content
    </div>
    <div class="project-bg" style="background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0JQxkW7.jpg') center center / cover;">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  position: relative;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.project {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

[class^="project-"],
.project-content,
.project-bg {
  height: 100%;
}

.project-content {
  padding: 75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: scale(.95);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.project-bg {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

/* Interactions */
[class^="project-"]:hover .project-content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.04);
}

[class^="project-"]:hover .project-bg {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.09);
}
```

I implemented a few helpful selectors to be more dynamic to your needs:

```
[class^="project-"] // Call on any project-# selector
```

Moving the transition property to the the main element and not interactions like hover, your in & out animations are applied across the board.

```
.project-content {
  padding: 75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: scale(.95);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```